# Django convert Date of Birth model field to Age

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-annotate

I have a Django class to convert the date of birth (dob) field in my model to age and annotate the result to a queryset.

```
class CalculateAge(Case):
    def __init__(self, model, field, condition=None, then=None, **lookups):
        today = date.today()
        obj = model.objects.first()
        field_object = model._meta.get_field(field)
        field_value = field_object.value_from_object(obj)
        bornyear = field_value.year
        bornmonth = field_value.month
        bornday = field_value.day
        # something is wrong with the next two lines
        age = [today.year - bornyear - ((today.month, today.day) < (bornmonth, bornday))]
        return super().__init__(*age, output_field=IntegerField())
```

however when I try to pass the result to my queryset

```
queryset = Person.objects.all().annotate(age=CalculateAge(Person, 'dob')
```

I get the error

```
Positional arguments must all be When objects.
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. CalculateAge is a class that extends Case but you use it like a function that returns a number. Are you sure you want CalculateAge to be a class and are you sure you want it to extend Case?

Comment: Case is not mandatory. Open to any implementation that can be used to populate the annotated value “age”

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way. Just add a function on your model to get the age like this:

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    #other fields

    def get_age(self):
        age = datetime.date.today()-self.birth_date
        return int((age).days/365.25)
```

Comment: This is just an approximation. For example if age.days == 365 this function returns 0 even though you're 1 year old.

Comment: You can just remove `int` or round up... depends what exactly you need it for.

Comment: And if age.days == 364 do you still round up? What about year 2000? That wasn't a leap year.

Comment: Like I said, depends what you need it for. But it would be fine in most cases.